# Get results of autocompletion search

Tags: python, html, autocomplete

I'm using beautifulsoup to get normal results from this site: http://www.pluzz.fr, but some results are only found by autocompletion.

I wonder if it's possible to get the results of autocompletion searchs, (like google when we write a word).

Is `beautifulsoup` helpful in this case? Or another module?

Comment: if any of the suggested solution works for you, I would suggest you to accept it. This way it would be shareable with others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you looking for the text value,
I would suggest to use [`lxml.html`](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html).

Once you start typing the following html will appear:

[image]

and you can easily navigate with XPath or id and get the vlaues.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's exactly what I've seen from my browser. I will study `lxml.html`